# How to change menu title (vertical to horizontal) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="~/Content/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/view/Nav/Menu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<string>     
@Html.ActionLink("Home","List","Product",null,
    new {@class ="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"})     
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
  @Html.RouteLink(link, new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = link, page = 1 }, 
     new{@class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg display:inline" }
  )
}
```

browser view

:[image]

i want to change item view like below picture .

how to make item arrange vertical to horizontal

[image]

Comment: Probably `display:inline-table` may work?

Comment: Please refer this guide from **W3Schools** [Horizontal Navigation Bar Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp).

Answer (score 1):

To make the buttons display horizontally just remove the `btn-block` class from the list of classes:

`new{@class = "btn btn-default btn-lg" }`

You don't need `display:inline` and that wouldn't work anyways because you included it in the `class` attribute. It has to be included in the `style` attribute because it is a CSS rule not a CSS class.

To remove the borders around the buttons like you have in your second screenshot you can override Bootstrap like this:
`style = border: 0;`

CSS rules included in the `style` attribute take precedence over CSS classes.